# How to fix my USB headset microphone (works for one second then input stops working)

Tags: 11.10, sound, microphone, headset

I am using a Plantronics Headset via USB. This worked flawlessly for a long time.

Now the microphone works for about 1 or 2 seconds when plugged in and then stops working. The hardware is alright (tested on other systems). Since this happens with Gnome or KDE alike I think there must be some flaw in the setup somewhere. Google couldn't help - so now I am looking for some help to cleanly set up the whole USB sound system.

How do I have to proceed to make sure the USB sound configuration is correct?

(running ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: you need to inform people of what version of ubuntu you are running.  recently i had audio input just stop working no matter what i do after a reinstall to a new version of the distro

Comment: correct sry, I forgot ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 solved it. Cheers!